# Would Javascript block access to certain regions of a site?

Tags: javascript

I was building my site recently, and it has an admin page. gyulasoos.com/admin.
It is protected by a javascript and firebase login mechanism.

It works this way:
the main container on site is set to display:none. The script checks the auth state with firebase, and if it finds that the user is authenticated, chances the container to display:block and everything becomes visible.

I was wondering if this is safe enough to block the bad guys, or with some scripting specific scripts could be disabled on the site showing the content.
My concern are raised because javascript is running on the client, and if a properly modified browser visits the page, might ignore some parts of it. Is this possible?

Comment: Nope, not safe at all. I can't tell you how many times I've enabled/disabled `display: none` on a website to see/hide stuff myself.

Answer (score 3):

Security should **not depend on the integrity of the client**.

If the content you're hidding behind the firebase login is sensitive, you need to make sure you don't serve it to the client until they're authenticated. On the other hand, if the client code makes authenticated API calls for sensitive info, then this should be fine.

Comment: If I save a cookie during login with a token, and later every php page would read this cookie before doing anything, would solve the problem? (everything on the site is generated by the php, so if I kill the app early, nothing is displayed)

Answer (score 0):

No. `display:none` is a styling property only and only makes the block not visible on the screen but the HTML and text are all available to the browser and anyone who has access to that.